# Grails default memory settings in IntelliJ

Tags: java, grails, intellij-idea, java-8, intellij-14

I am using Grails 2.5.1 and Java 8 with IntelliJ 14.1.4. Whenever I run any grails command (eg: clean) using the Grails Run Target (Ctrl+Alt+g), IntelliJ executes the below command:

> C:\iDocs\Programs\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\java -Dgrails.home=C:\iDocs\Programs\grails-2.5.1 -Dbase.dir=C:\iDocs\xxxx -Dtools.jar=C:\iDocs\Programs\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\lib\tools.jar -Dgroovy.starter.conf=C:\iDocs\Programs\grails-2.5.1/conf/groovy-starter.conf ***-Xmx768M -Xms768M -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:PermSize=256m*** -Djline.WindowsTerminal.directConsole=false -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -classpath C:\iDocs\Programs\grails-2.5.1\lib\org.codehaus.groovy\groovy-all\jars\groovy-all-2.4.4.jar;C:\iDocs\Programs\grails-2.5.1\dist\grails-bootstrap-2.5.1.jar org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter --main org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner --conf C:\iDocs\Programs\grails-2.5.1/conf/groovy-starter.conf "clean -plain-output"

Can anyone give me the location for this VM configuration (highlighted above) that I can edit, especially the PermSize and MaxPermSize?

UPDATE: 
Note: 
a) Adding it to VM options on Run Target window doesnt modify it.
b) Adding it to the VM options of IntelliJ executeable (idea64.exe.vmoptions) also doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted the IntelliJ support and unfortunately, it is not supported by the IDE. An issue has been created to track the same:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-145433

If anyone is facing the same issue, please upvote the issue created (IDEA-145433) and comment in there.

Comment: Has this issue been fixed and if it has, what is the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Go to (IntelliJ installation bin directory):

```
<Installation Dir>/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA <version>/bin
```

Modify:

```
idea.exe.vmoptions
idea64.exe.vmoption
```

This is in context to a windows setup. You can find the corresponding in OSX.

UPDATE:
For Grails application, setting up `GRAILS_OPTS` as environment variables is also an option.

Comment: I have already tried it and it doesnt work. Thank you for mentioning it, I will add it to my question as a note.

Comment: You can also try adding `GRAILS_OPTS` as an environment variable. Make sure to restart IntelliJ after that.

Comment: Did that and provided ONLY the Xms and Xmx values in it. When I start IntelliJ, it reads the updated values of Xms and Xmx, but additionally, it adds the PermSize and MaxPermSize default values automatically to it. Any way around to stop these two values from getting added?

Comment: PermGen should not matter in JDK 8. You can ignore. If you want to actually remove them then find then in PATH/CLASSPATH if it has been set anywhere. Updated my answer with regards to GRAILS_OPTS.

Comment: Yes, I want to remove it. And nope, I have not set them anywhere in the path variable. Is there anyway to remove these two options?